# What's the meaning of !!x

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Currently I'm working on an Angular 4/Typescript project.
Yesterday, while debugging a part of the application, I saw an operator I've never seen before:

[image]

Obviously I asked the other team members about it and they couldn't provide an answer, they just told me that it seemed to be some sort of special operator.

Today I've been googling about it withouth any success. I also checked on the Node.js console and it appears to be just as expected, a double negation that simply converts truthy to true and falsy to false.
Wouln't these two statements produce the same effect?

```
if (x) // do something

if (!!x) // do something
```

Hence my question: 
It is actually some sort of special operator or workaround to get something done, or it's just a missconcenption of some developer?

Comment: It's just a double negation. The ! operator is often used to convert something to a boolean in JavaScript.

Comment: I think first not operator converts the value to a boolean, and the second not operator will negate it.

Comment: @Taha That sounds way more complicated than it is. `!` converts any value to a boolean `true` or `false` and `!` negates that again, essentially it's a *truthy/falsey* to `true`/`false` conversion. Which is entirely superfluous here and doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yep I couldn't be so sure so I removed the last sentence. Got an headache just now :)

Comment: Sidenote: if *one* junior developer can't figure it out… fair enough. If an entire *team* can't… :-/

Comment: @deceze, BTW I think the first operator doesn't convert it to a boolean, it negates the variable converted to a boolean. Is it right?

Comment: @Taha Well, yes, it converts it to the *opposite* boolean.

Comment: @deceze I did figure it out, but as you said, I simply assummed it has to be some sort of special technique, because, as you have said, in this case it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @mdarefull Completely off-the-rails warning: if the answer you got was "probably some special operator" and nobody deleted it, your team may be prone to [cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Beware.

Comment: @deceze Thanks a lot! At least I got something useful out of a dup question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a double boolean negation - basically a cheap way to turn any value into a pure boolean true/false.

Comment: Would that change in any way the effects on an if statement? Is there any difference with just doing if(x)???

Comment: @mdarefull Nope, `!!` can be omitted entirely without making a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a double negation. The ! operator is often used to convert something to a boolean in JavaScript.

```js
var undefinedVar = undefined;
console.log(!undefinedVar);
console.log(!!undefinedVar);

var nullVar = null;
console.log(!nullVar);
console.log(!!nullVar);

var trueVar = true;
console.log(!trueVar);
console.log(!!trueVar);

var falseVar = false;
console.log(!falseVar);
console.log(!!falseVar);
```